# AngularJS creating new table foreach result property

Tags: html, angularjs, html-table, angularjs-material

I don't know how to word this issue properly as English being my second language but essentially I am trying to create new table `forEach` results property in the array. Here is what my response from API looks like.

```
response.providerResults =  [
     "totalHits":49934,
     "results":[  
        {  
           "title":"Apple Bans Cryptocurrency Mining on iPhone and iPad",
           "summary":"Apple Bans Cryptocurrency Mining on iPhone and iPad\nIndo-Asian News ...Service\n, 12 June 2018\nThe iPhone maker Apple has introduced a...",
           "sourceName":"SocialGist",
           "url":"https://gadgets.ndtv.com/apps/news/apple-bans-cryptocurrency-mining-on-iphone-and-ipad-1866149",
           "date":"201806121009",
           "id":"12630772075",
           "lang":"English",
           "username":null,
           "followerCount":0
        },
        {  
           "title":"Living with the BMW X2, Living with the BMW X2",
           "summary":"... Apple CarPlay for controlling your iPhone via the car, though. 'Two...",
           "sourceName":"SocialGist",
           "url":"http://www.chichester.co.uk/cars/car-reviews/living-with-the-bmw-x2_9055aa7527c911c0e34497579a7e75bc/",
           "date":"201806121008",
           "id":"12618939012",
           "lang":"English",
           "username":null,
           "followerCount":0
        },
        {  
           "title":" Art Art Artist’s Facebook Page Is Auctioned Off for $115, Promptly Covered in Dick Pics This is what happens when you hand over control of your online persona. Kari Paul 5.18.15 ",
           "summary":"... is planning to sell his iPhone and all of the open...",
           "sourceName":"SocialGist",
           "url":"http://motherboard.vice.com/en_us/article/kbz4ya/artists-facebook-page-is-auctioned-off-for-115-promptly-covered-in-dick-pics",
           "date":"201806121007",
           "id":"13510512572",
           "lang":"English",
           "username":null,
           "followerCount":0
        },
        {  
           "title":" Gaming Gaming The Adorable Japanese Cat Game Everyone Was Obsessed With Is Now in English Neko Atsume: Kitty Collector is going global. Emanuel Maiberg 10.30.15 ",
           "summary":"... English translation coming to the iPhone \"very soon.\" This is according...",
           "sourceName":"SocialGist",
           "url":"http://motherboard.vice.com/en_us/article/aekwnb/the-adorable-japanese-cat-game-everyone-was-obsessed-with-is-now-in-english",
           "date":"201806121007",
           "id":"13510513340",
           "lang":"English",
           "username":null,
           "followerCount":0
        },
        {  
           "title":" Culture Culture As Tech Giants Enter Iran, Microsoft Hangs Back Despite sanctions lifting, the Microsoft Store still isn t available in Iran. Joseph Cox 10.20.14 ",
           "summary":"... as selling its Mac and iPhone range to customers planning on...",
           "sourceName":"SocialGist",
           "url":"http://motherboard.vice.com/en_us/article/4x34bw/technology-after-sanctions-in-iran",
           "date":"201806121007",
           "id":"13510507708",
           "lang":"English",
           "username":null,
           "followerCount":0
        },
        {  
           "title":" Apple warns suppliers that iPhone demand is falling - report ",
           "summary":"... of 100 million iPhone 8, iPhone 8 Plus and iPhone X devices. This... OLED displays, similar to the iPhone X. The budget model will... for a while now that iPhone sales are flattening. Apple shipped...",
           "sourceName":"SocialGist",
           "url":"http://www.kvia.com/lifestyle/technology/apple-warns-suppliers-that-iphone-demand-falling-report/750757527",
           "date":"201806121006",
           "id":"13190692496",
           "lang":"English",
           "username":null,
           "followerCount":0
        },
        {  
           "title":"Painterly reflections",
           "summary":"... photo he took on his iPhone a week earlier. On his...",
           "sourceName":"SocialGist",
           "url":"https://www.almanacnews.com/news/show_story.php?id=24782&e=y",
           "date":"201806121006",
           "id":"14280721174",
           "lang":"English",
           "username":null,
           "followerCount":0
        },
        {  
           "title":" Opinion OPINION: The Australian government can't be trusted with our digital IDs ",
           "summary":"... the FBI from unlocking an iPhone owned by a known terrorist...",
           "sourceName":"SocialGist",
           "url":"https://www.communitynews.com.au/eastern-reporter/opinion/australian-government-cant-trusted-digital-ids",
           "date":"201806121006",
           "id":"12846878518",
           "lang":"English",
           "username":null,
           "followerCount":0
        },
        {  
           "title":"Facebook Memories lets you relive cherished moments – and block out bad ones",
           "summary":"...\nWe reveal the best upcoming iPhone features Apple DIDN'T talk...",
           "sourceName":"SocialGist",
           "url":"https://www.thesun.ie/tech/2700087/facebook-memories-lets-you-relive-cherished-moments-and-block-out-bad-ones/",
           "date":"201806121005",
           "id":"13081383171",
           "lang":"English",
           "username":null,
           "followerCount":0
        },
        {  
           "title":"Trial underway for Barnesville man charged with supplying drugs to woman who died from overdose",
           "summary":"... heroin after Kropp sold an iPhone to a woman in Hazleton...",
           "sourceName":"SocialGist",
           "url":"http://www.republicanherald.com/news/trial-underway-for-barnesville-man-charged-with-supplying-drugs-to-woman-who-died-from-overdose-1.2348459",
           "date":"201806121004",
           "id":"14759784749",
           "lang":"English",
           "username":null,
           "followerCount":0
        }
     ],
     "providerName":"News",
     "next":"10",
     "success":true,
     "message":"",
     "warnings":[  

     ],
     "elapsed":517
  },
  {  
     "totalHits":13322,
     "results":[  
        {  
           "title":"Nice Upgrade",
           "summary":"Upgrading from a well-worn (and very faithful) 5C.Took a little getting used to.Only real “downside” is the disappearance of the headphone jack. The lightning dongle is too easy to misplace/lose.",
           "sourceName":"SocialGist",
           "url":"https://www.uscellular.com/devices/phones/apple-iphone-7-jet-black-256Gb.html?productId=prod7440154",
           "date":"201806120006",
           "id":"2123181692",
           "lang":"English",
           "username":null,
           "followerCount":0
        },
        {  
           "title":"",
           "summary":"I have an iPhone X 64g in Silver. It ...",
           "sourceName":"SocialGist",
           "url":"http://www.consumeraffairs.com/cell_phones/asurion.html",
           "date":"201806120000",
           "id":"2125654513",
           "lang":"English",
           "username":null,
           "followerCount":0
        },
        {  
           "title":"Love my phone!",
           "summary":"Love my phone except for the fact that it continues to download my email back to 2016. The guys at the store have clicked the settings but it continues to do so.",
           "sourceName":"SocialGist",
           "url":"https://www.uscellular.com/devices/phones/apple-iphone-8-plus-gold-256gb.html?productId=prod12220164",
           "date":"201806112327",
           "id":"2142157873",
           "lang":"English",
           "username":null,
           "followerCount":0
        },
        {  
           "title":"Great phone",
           "summary":"I love the upgrades to the camera.",
           "sourceName":"SocialGist",
           "url":"https://www.att.com/cellphones/iphone/apple-iphone-8-plus.html#sku=sku8510273",
           "date":"201806111833",
           "id":"2130461600",
           "lang":"English",
           "username":null,
           "followerCount":0
        },
        {  
           "title":"iPhone 8",
           "summary":"So glad I upgraded from the 6, everything seems better with the 8, Photos are clearer on my 6 they always had a yellow tint, seems to do things faster also. I really like the fact that it isn’t any larger than the 6, not to mention it’s RED which I have been waiting for in an iPhone!",
           "sourceName":"SocialGist",
           "url":"https://www.att.com/cellphones/iphone/apple-iphone-8.html#sku=sku8870319",
           "date":"201806111616",
           "id":"2121280457",
           "lang":"English",
           "username":null,
           "followerCount":0
        },
        {  
           "title":"Feel sexy & more!",
           "summary":"... use the pockets for my iPhone 7 Plus when I walk...",
           "sourceName":"SocialGist",
           "url":"http://athleta.gap.com/browse/product.do?pid=209929002",
           "date":"201806110919",
           "id":"2099205309",
           "lang":"English",
           "username":null,
           "followerCount":0
        },
        {  
           "title":"Lovely Sensible iPhone Choice",
           "summary":"... they all agreed that an iPhone SE 32GB was the right... to scroll after my ancient iPhone 5. Very happy with my...",
           "sourceName":"SocialGist",
           "url":"http://www.productreview.com.au/p/apple-iphone-se.html",
           "date":"201806110000",
           "id":"2103479928",
           "lang":"English",
           "username":null,
           "followerCount":0
        },
        {  
           "title":"Poor iPhone Screen Repair",
           "summary":"... Crazy a go as my iPhone 7 needed a screen replacement.... Comparing it to a genuine iPhone screen the colour and clarity...",
           "sourceName":"SocialGist",
           "url":"https://uk.trustpilot.com/reviews/5b1e49a76d33bc0fd864f16d",
           "date":"201806110000",
           "id":"2116152806",
           "lang":"English",
           "username":null,
           "followerCount":0
        },
        {  
           "title":"Beest lightning flash drive",
           "summary":"Amazing product! I recommend this product to anyone that wants to transfer pics from the iPhone. It is fast and reliable. I have never had an issue.",
           "sourceName":"SocialGist",
           "url":"https://www.amazon.com/SanDisk-iXpand-iPhone-Silver-SDIX30C-128G-GN6NE/product-reviews/B01CIEBXZG/ref=cm_cr_arp_d_rvw_fmt?sortBy=bySubmissionDateDescending&reviewerType=all_reviews&formatType=current_format",
           "date":"201806110000",
           "id":"2097486181",
           "lang":"English",
           "username":null,
           "followerCount":0
        },
        {  
           "title":"Great little phone",
           "summary":"Just purchased my second Iphone SE. It's a great little phone and its never let me down first one I bought was two years ago and still going strong. Its a great size and with an upgrade to 36Gb well worth the money. I would recommend to anyone on a budget $45 a month you can't go wrong especially for us oldies.",
           "sourceName":"SocialGist",
           "url":"http://www.productreview.com.au/p/apple-iphone-se.html",
           "date":"201806110000",
           "id":"2124758113",
           "lang":"English",
           "username":null,
           "followerCount":0
        }
     ],
     "providerName":"Reviews",
     "next":"10",
     "success":true,
     "message":"",
     "warnings":[  

     ],
     "elapsed":1391
  },
  {  
     "totalHits":40016,
     "results":[  
        {  
           "title":"A Parents' Guide To Fortnite, GTA V, Call Of Duty, Roblox And Minecraft",
           "summary":"... cartoon-like graphics, availability on iPhone, Xbox and PlayStation and the... players of any age. On iPhone and iPad there’s a...",
           "sourceName":"SocialGist",
           "url":"https://www.huffingtonpost.co.uk/entry/fortnite-and-other-video-games-parents-guide_uk_5b15399ce4b0d5e89e21a70e",
           "date":"201806121008",
           "id":"12518829726",
           "lang":"English",
           "username":null,
           "followerCount":0
        },
        {  
           "title":"A Parents' Guide To Fortnite, GTA V, Call Of Duty, Roblox And Minecraft",
           "summary":"... cartoon-like graphics, availability on iPhone, Xbox and PlayStation and the... players of any age. On iPhone and iPad there’s a...",
           "sourceName":"SocialGist",
           "url":"https://www.huffingtonpost.co.uk/entry/fortnite-and-parents-guideother-video-games-parents-guide_uk_5b15399ce4b0d5e89e21a70e",
           "date":"201806121008",
           "id":"12842403173",
           "lang":"English",
           "username":null,
           "followerCount":0
        },
        {  
           "title":"The 5 Greatest BlackBerry Movement Cases And Covers You Can Discover",
           "summary":"... an analogous worth to the iPhone. Presents a report on Brazil... decide assigned your case. With iPhone having gone from boring to...",
           "sourceName":"SocialGist",
           "url":"http://ellington28tuttle.blog.fc2.com/blog-entry-1.html",
           "date":"201806121008",
           "id":"13610660982",
           "lang":"English",
           "username":null,
           "followerCount":0
        },
        {  
           "title":"#GrandSale: Multi-Purpose Power Bank Diary with 16 GB Pen Drive at the Lowest Price!!",
           "summary":"PAN India Delivery | Super Sale | Grab Now | Stock Limited ‌    IPhone and Android Charging Everywhere    You Go!    Note Your Important Tasks And Carry    Your Data Everywhere In 16 GB Pen Drive!                  Unsubscribe from further emails ",
           "sourceName":"SocialGist",
           "url":"http://su2008.blogspot.com/2018/06/grandsale-multi-purpose-power-bank_12.html",
           "date":"201806121006",
           "id":"13391419360",
           "lang":"English",
           "username":null,
           "followerCount":0
        },
        {  
           "title":"MARVELL MINIPOINT DRIVERS FOR MAC",
           "summary":"... the original first-generation Apple iPhone. By using this site, you...",
           "sourceName":"SocialGist",
           "url":"http://gracechurchblog.com/marvell-minipoint-22/",
           "date":"201806121004",
           "id":"13159247849",
           "lang":"English",
           "username":null,
           "followerCount":0
        },
        {  
           "title":"Apple to officially bless USB-C with 2019 iPhone",
           "summary":"... bless USB-C with 2019 iPhone",
           "sourceName":"SocialGist",
           "url":"https://mspoweruser.com/apple-to-officially-bless-usb-c-with-2019-iphone/",
           "date":"201806121000",
           "id":"13610695286",
           "lang":"English",
           "username":null,
           "followerCount":0
        },
        {  
           "title":"ListVR iPhone app offers a new way to create 360-degree tours",
           "summary":"ListVR is an iPhone app that connects to 360-capable cameras, notably the industry-popular Ricoh Theta, to help listing agents rapidly prepare and share panoramic property tours. ",
           "sourceName":"SocialGist",
           "url":"https://www.inman.com/2018/06/12/listvr-iphone-app-offers-a-new-way-to-create-360-degree-tours/",
           "date":"201806121000",
           "id":"14395504944",
           "lang":"English",
           "username":null,
           "followerCount":0
        },
        {  
           "title":"ListVR iPhone app offers a new way to create 360-degree tours",
           "summary":"ListVR is an iPhone app that connects to 360-capable cameras, notably the industry-popular Ricoh Theta, to help listing agents rapidly prepare and share panoramic property tours.",
           "sourceName":"SocialGist",
           "url":"http://helenatalbot.com/real-estate-news/listvr-iphone-app-offers-a-new-way-to-create-360-degree-tours/",
           "date":"201806121000",
           "id":"12619064452",
           "lang":"English",
           "username":null,
           "followerCount":0
        },
        {  
           "title":"My tweets",
           "summary":"... that the tunes on my iPhone go back five decades...train...",
           "sourceName":"SocialGist",
           "url":"https://semi-retired.livejournal.com/273159.html",
           "date":"201806121000",
           "id":"14172002854",
           "lang":"English",
           "username":null,
           "followerCount":0
        },
        {  
           "title":"7 Retail Marketing Predictions to Watch for in 2018",
           "summary":"... into Apple products, including the iPhone. This should encourage retailers to... their home. By using their iPhone to scan the floor of...",
           "sourceName":"SocialGist",
           "url":"https://www.shutterstock.com/blog/retail-marketing-predictions-2018",
           "date":"201806121000",
           "id":"13498756944",
           "lang":"English",
           "username":null,
           "followerCount":0
        }
     ],
     "providerName":"Blogs",
     "next":"10",
     "success":true,
     "message":"",
     "warnings":[  

     ],
     "elapsed":1470
  },
  {  
     "totalHits":256648,
     "results":[  
        {  
           "title":"Re: Interesting Find",
           "summary":"I’m just glad you lost Interest in that civic! \n\n\nSent from my iPhone using Tapatalk",
           "sourceName":"SocialGist",
           "url":"http://www.silveradosierra.com/viewtopic.php?t=698984",
           "date":"201806121007",
           "id":"64274658187",
           "lang":"English",
           "username":null,
           "followerCount":0
        },
        {  
           "title":"RE: June OG Thread",
           "summary":"... help! [emoji6]   \nBabbled from my iPhone using Tapatalk",
           "sourceName":"SocialGist",
           "url":"http://www.myproana.com/index.php?showtopic=3437490",
           "date":"201806121007",
           "id":"54643172018",
           "lang":"English",
           "username":null,
           "followerCount":0
        },
        {  
           "title":"RE: I've sold a few seiko's and bought a Tudor.",
           "summary":"[QUOTE=tritto;2623213]Very nice, Paul. \nAlways good to sell a few watches to get something special. \nI've been lucky enough to try on a BB for size, but it wasn't for me. One day I hope to raise funds for a BB58, if it's as good as they say it it. \n\n\nSent from my iPhone using Tapatalk[/QUOTE]\nThanks, the 58 is very nice, go for it.",
           "sourceName":"SocialGist",
           "url":"http://www.thewatchsite.com/showpost.php?p=2623285",
           "date":"201806121006",
           "id":"45444078634",
           "lang":"English",
           "username":null,
           "followerCount":0
        },
        {  
           "title":"Re: The Brotherhood of Submariner Homages  (a/k/a BSHT) (Part 26)",
           "summary":"... reading that. \n\n\nSent from my iPhone using Tapatalk",
           "sourceName":"SocialGist",
           "url":"http://forums.watchuseek.com/showpost.php?p=46266443",
           "date":"201806121006",
           "id":"73149119344",
           "lang":"English",
           "username":null,
           "followerCount":0
        },
        {  
           "title":"RE: Hip X-Rays, what do you think?",
           "summary":"... really worried. \n\n\nSent from my iPhone using Tapatalk",
           "sourceName":"SocialGist",
           "url":"http://www.goldenretrieverforum.com/showpost.php?p=7633612",
           "date":"201806121003",
           "id":"47586878135",
           "lang":"English",
           "username":null,
           "followerCount":0
        },
        {  
           "title":"RE: finally got around to doing a “first wax”",
           "summary":"[quote=kastner03;260386]believe it or not i enjoy doing it when i have the time,  finding the time is the hard part lol\n\n\n Sent from my iPhone using Tapatalk[/quote]\n\n\nMe too.  I find it very \"medicinal\".",
           "sourceName":"SocialGist",
           "url":"http://www.terrainforum.net/showpost.php?p=260450",
           "date":"201806121001",
           "id":"67999278969",
           "lang":"English",
           "username":null,
           "followerCount":0
        },
        {  
           "title":"RE: 突然想买个二手果机.发现这里大部分比二手平台还要贵",
           "summary":"                                      二手全原iphone+V:yuyang2031                ",
           "sourceName":"SocialGist",
           "url":"http://tieba.baidu.com/p/5738028280#post_content_120238939677",
           "date":"201806121000",
           "id":"40498750044",
           "lang":"English",
           "username":null,
           "followerCount":0
        },
        {  
           "title":"RE: Filter Box Cover Question",
           "summary":"[QUOTE=Lt4Mike;2357289]I’m at lunch at the moment so I’ll double check but I’m pretty sure it is a sort of carbon filter. Give me about an hour and I’ll be back. \n\n\nSent from my iPhone using Tapatalk[/QUOTE]\n\nman, that's a long lunch break!  lol",
           "sourceName":"SocialGist",
           "url":"http://www.ctsvowners.com/forum/showpost.php?p=2358281",
           "date":"201806120958",
           "id":"49424983244",
           "lang":"English",
           "username":null,
           "followerCount":0
        },
        {  
           "title":"Re: Plug wire Resistance",
           "summary":"You’re due for a plug wire change anyway. Unless you have a high tension lead tester, you’re not going to get a perfect reading on them. \n\n\nSent from my iPhone using Tapatalk",
           "sourceName":"SocialGist",
           "url":"http://www.silveradosierra.com/viewtopic.php?t=698964",
           "date":"201806120957",
           "id":"64274499979",
           "lang":"English",
           "username":null,
           "followerCount":0
        },
        {  
           "title":"Bond update:",
           "summary":"... of September's new iPhone announcement. Remember, historically this runs...",
           "sourceName":"SocialGist",
           "url":"http://investorshub.advfn.com/boards/read_msg.aspx?message_id=141473816",
           "date":"201806120956",
           "id":"90775052429",
           "lang":"English",
           "username":null,
           "followerCount":0
        }
     ];
```

So I am trying to create a table for each **results** property for each provider. I tried using `forEach` method but I am only able to show one table. Here is what I am doing in HTML

```
<div>
  <md-content flex>
    <table flex>
      <tr>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th></th>
        <th>Time</th>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="row in 
                   providerResponseResults.results">
        <td><a style="color:black; text-decoration:none" href="{{ row.url }}">{{ row.title.slice(0, 150) }}</a></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>{{ row.date }}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </md-content>
</div>
```

Here's what I tried in my `forEach`. The values in `response.providerResults` is same as above

```
response.providerResults.forEach(function(results) {
  $scope.providerResponseResults = results;
});
```

Comment: That `.forEach()` is just going to replace `$scope.providerResponseResults` each time and you'll end up with a single object (the last one) at the end. You need to use nested `ng-repeat`s in your view. One (outer) to loop each results object and then one (inner) to loop the key/value pairs.

Comment: you have an invalid JSON, instead of `response.providerResults =  [ ... ]` you need `response.providerResults =  { ... }`. Then It's enough to just do: `$scope.providerResponseResults = response.providerResults;` for your table to work

Comment: @AlekseySolovey It's an array of objects so the outer brackets are correct, but it's missing a `{` after the opening `[` to define the first object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The json you posted had a couple issues: missing a `{` for the first object in the array as well as a misplaced `]` in one of the elements. After fixing that, here is one way you could loop the results and display them in tables. If you always know that the properties of the objects in the `results` array are the same you could eliminate the `ng-repeat` that builds the table column headers.

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.response = {};
    $scope.response.providerResults = [{
      "totalHits": 49934,
      "results": [{
          "title": "Apple Bans Cryptocurrency Mining on iPhone and iPad",
          "summary": "Apple Bans Cryptocurrency Mining on iPhone and iPad\nIndo-Asian News ...Service\n, 12 June 2018\nThe iPhone maker Apple has introduced a...",
          "sourceName": "SocialGist",
          "url": "https://gadgets.ndtv.com/apps/news/apple-bans-cryptocurrency-mining-on-iphone-and-ipad-1866149",
          "date": "201806121009",
          "id": "12630772075",
          "lang": "English",
          "username": null,
          "followerCount": 0
        },
        {
          "title": "Living with the BMW X2, Living with the BMW X2",
          "summary": "... Apple CarPlay for controlling your iPhone via the car, though. 'Two...",
          "sourceName": "SocialGist",
          "url": "http://www.chichester.co.uk/cars/car-reviews/living-with-the-bmw-x2_9055aa7527c911c0e34497579a7e75bc/",
          "date": "201806121008",
          "id": "12618939012",
          "lang": "English",
          "username": null,
          "followerCount": 0
        },
        {
          "title": " Art Art Artist’s Facebook Page Is Auctioned Off for $115, Promptly Covered in Dick Pics This is what happens when you hand over control of your online persona. Kari Paul 5.18.15 ",
          "summary": "... is planning to sell his iPhone and all of the open...",
          "sourceName": "SocialGist",
          "url": "http://motherboard.vice.com/en_us/article/kbz4ya/artists-facebook-page-is-auctioned-off-for-115-promptly-covered-in-dick-pics",
          "date": "201806121007",
          "id": "13510512572",
          "lang": "English",
          "username": null,
          "followerCount": 0
        },
        {
          "title": " Gaming Gaming The Adorable Japanese Cat Game Everyone Was Obsessed With Is Now in English Neko Atsume: Kitty Collector is going global. Emanuel Maiberg 10.30.15 ",
          "summary": "... English translation coming to the iPhone \"very soon.\" This is according...",
          "sourceName": "SocialGist",
          "url": "http://motherboard.vice.com/en_us/article/aekwnb/the-adorable-japanese-cat-game-everyone-was-obsessed-with-is-now-in-english",
          "date": "201806121007",
          "id": "13510513340",
          "lang": "English",
          "username": null,
          "followerCount": 0
        },
        {
          "title": " Culture Culture As Tech Giants Enter Iran, Microsoft Hangs Back Despite sanctions lifting, the Microsoft Store still isn t available in Iran. Joseph Cox 10.20.14 ",
          "summary": "... as selling its Mac and iPhone range to customers planning on...",
          "sourceName": "SocialGist",
          "url": "http://motherboard.vice.com/en_us/article/4x34bw/technology-after-sanctions-in-iran",
          "date": "201806121007",
          "id": "13510507708",
          "lang": "English",
          "username": null,
          "followerCount": 0
        },
        {
          "title": " Apple warns suppliers that iPhone demand is falling - report ",
          "summary": "... of 100 million iPhone 8, iPhone 8 Plus and iPhone X devices. This... OLED displays, similar to the iPhone X. The budget model will... for a while now that iPhone sales are flattening. Apple shipped...",
          "sourceName": "SocialGist",
          "url": "http://www.kvia.com/lifestyle/technology/apple-warns-suppliers-that-iphone-demand-falling-report/750757527",
          "date": "201806121006",
          "id": "13190692496",
          "lang": "English",
          "username": null,
          "followerCount": 0
        },
        {
          "title": "Painterly reflections",
          "summary": "... photo he took on his iPhone a week earlier. On his...",
          "sourceName": "SocialGist",
          "url": "https://www.almanacnews.com/news/show_story.php?id=24782&e=y",
          "date": "201806121006",
          "id": "14280721174",
          "lang": "English",
          "username": null,
          "followerCount": 0
        },
        {
          "title": " Opinion OPINION: The Australian government can't be trusted with our digital IDs ",
          "summary": "... the FBI from unlocking an iPhone owned by a known terrorist...",
          "sourceName": "SocialGist",
          "url": "https://www.communitynews.com.au/eastern-reporter/opinion/australian-government-cant-trusted-digital-ids",
          "date": "201806121006",
          "id": "12846878518",
          "lang": "English",
          "username": null,
          "followerCount": 0
        },
        {
          "title": "Facebook Memories lets you relive cherished moments – and block out bad ones",
          "summary": "...\nWe reveal the best upcoming iPhone features Apple DIDN'T talk...",
          "sourceName": "SocialGist",
          "url": "https://www.thesun.ie/tech/2700087/facebook-memories-lets-you-relive-cherished-moments-and-block-out-bad-ones/",
          "date": "201806121005",
          "id": "13081383171",
          "lang": "English",
          "username": null,
          "followerCount": 0
        },
        {
          "title": "Trial underway for Barnesville man charged with supplying drugs to woman who died from overdose",
          "summary": "... heroin after Kropp sold an iPhone to a woman in Hazleton...",
          "sourceName": "SocialGist",
          "url": "http://www.republicanherald.com/news/trial-underway-for-barnesville-man-charged-with-supplying-drugs-to-woman-who-died-from-overdose-1.2348459",
          "date": "201806121004",
          "id": "14759784749",
          "lang": "English",
          "username": null,
          "followerCount": 0
        }
      ],
      "providerName": "News",
      "next": "10",
      "success": true,
      "message": "",
      "warnings": [

      ],
      "elapsed": 517
    }, {
      "totalHits": 13322,
      "results": [{
          "title": "Nice Upgrade",
          "summary": "Upgrading from a well-worn (and very faithful) 5C.Took a little getting used to.Only real “downside” is the disappearance of the headphone jack. The lightning dongle is too easy to misplace/lose.",
          "sourceName": "SocialGist",
          "url": "https://www.uscellular.com/devices/phones/apple-iphone-7-jet-black-256Gb.html?productId=prod7440154",
          "date": "201806120006",
          "id": "2123181692",
          "lang": "English",
          "username": null,
          "followerCount": 0
        },
        {
          "title": "",
          "summary": "I have an iPhone X 64g in Silver. It ...",
          "sourceName": "SocialGist",
          "url": "http://www.consumeraffairs.com/cell_phones/asurion.html",
          "date": "201806120000",
          "id": "2125654513",
          "lang": "English",
          "username": null,
          "followerCount": 0
        },
        {
          "title": "Love my phone!",
          "summary": "Love my phone except for the fact that it continues to download my email back to 2016. The guys at the store have clicked the settings but it continues to do so.",
          "sourceName": "SocialGist",
          "url": "https://www.uscellular.com/devices/phones/apple-iphone-8-plus-gold-256gb.html?productId=prod12220164",
          "date": "201806112327",
          "id": "2142157873",
          "lang": "English",
          "username": null,
          "followerCount": 0
        },
        {
          "title": "Great phone",
          "summary": "I love the upgrades to the camera.",
          "sourceName": "SocialGist",
          "url": "https://www.att.com/cellphones/iphone/apple-iphone-8-plus.html#sku=sku8510273",
          "date": "201806111833",
          "id": "2130461600",
          "lang": "English",
          "username": null,
          "followerCount": 0
        },
        {
          "title": "iPhone 8",
          "summary": "So glad I upgraded from the 6, everything seems better with the 8, Photos are clearer on my 6 they always had a yellow tint, seems to do things faster also. I really like the fact that it isn’t any larger than the 6, not to mention it’s RED which I have been waiting for in an iPhone!",
          "sourceName": "SocialGist",
          "url": "https://www.att.com/cellphones/iphone/apple-iphone-8.html#sku=sku8870319",
          "date": "201806111616",
          "id": "2121280457",
          "lang": "English",
          "username": null,
          "followerCount": 0
        },
        {
          "title": "Feel sexy & more!",
          "summary": "... use the pockets for my iPhone 7 Plus when I walk...",
          "sourceName": "SocialGist",
          "url": "http://athleta.gap.com/browse/product.do?pid=209929002",
          "date": "201806110919",
          "id": "2099205309",
          "lang": "English",
          "username": null,
          "followerCount": 0
        },
        {
          "title": "Lovely Sensible iPhone Choice",
          "summary": "... they all agreed that an iPhone SE 32GB was the right... to scroll after my ancient iPhone 5. Very happy with my...",
          "sourceName": "SocialGist",
          "url": "http://www.productreview.com.au/p/apple-iphone-se.html",
          "date": "201806110000",
          "id": "2103479928",
          "lang": "English",
          "username": null,
          "followerCount": 0
        },
        {
          "title": "Poor iPhone Screen Repair",
          "summary": "... Crazy a go as my iPhone 7 needed a screen replacement.... Comparing it to a genuine iPhone screen the colour and clarity...",
          "sourceName": "SocialGist",
          "url": "https://uk.trustpilot.com/reviews/5b1e49a76d33bc0fd864f16d",
          "date": "201806110000",
          "id": "2116152806",
          "lang": "English",
          "username": null,
          "followerCount": 0
        },
        {
          "title": "Beest lightning flash drive",
          "summary": "Amazing product! I recommend this product to anyone that wants to transfer pics from the iPhone. It is fast and reliable. I have never had an issue.",
          "sourceName": "SocialGist",
          "url": "https://www.amazon.com/SanDisk-iXpand-iPhone-Silver-SDIX30C-128G-GN6NE/product-reviews/B01CIEBXZG/ref=cm_cr_arp_d_rvw_fmt?sortBy=bySubmissionDateDescending&reviewerType=all_reviews&formatType=current_format",
          "date": "201806110000",
          "id": "2097486181",
          "lang": "English",
          "username": null,
          "followerCount": 0
        },
        {
          "title": "Great little phone",
          "summary": "Just purchased my second Iphone SE. It's a great little phone and its never let me down first one I bought was two years ago and still going strong. Its a great size and with an upgrade to 36Gb well worth the money. I would recommend to anyone on a budget $45 a month you can't go wrong especially for us oldies.",
          "sourceName": "SocialGist",
          "url": "http://www.productreview.com.au/p/apple-iphone-se.html",
          "date": "201806110000",
          "id": "2124758113",
          "lang": "English",
          "username": null,
          "followerCount": 0
        }
      ],
      "providerName": "Reviews",
      "next": "10",
      "success": true,
      "message": "",
      "warnings": [

      ],
      "elapsed": 1391
    }, {
      "totalHits": 40016,
      "results": [{
          "title": "A Parents' Guide To Fortnite, GTA V, Call Of Duty, Roblox And Minecraft",
          "summary": "... cartoon-like graphics, availability on iPhone, Xbox and PlayStation and the... players of any age. On iPhone and iPad there’s a...",
          "sourceName": "SocialGist",
          "url": "https://www.huffingtonpost.co.uk/entry/fortnite-and-other-video-games-parents-guide_uk_5b15399ce4b0d5e89e21a70e",
          "date": "201806121008",
          "id": "12518829726",
          "lang": "English",
          "username": null,
          "followerCount": 0
        },
        {
          "title": "A Parents' Guide To Fortnite, GTA V, Call Of Duty, Roblox And Minecraft",
          "summary": "... cartoon-like graphics, availability on iPhone, Xbox and PlayStation and the... players of any age. On iPhone and iPad there’s a...",
          "sourceName": "SocialGist",
          "url": "https://www.huffingtonpost.co.uk/entry/fortnite-and-parents-guideother-video-games-parents-guide_uk_5b15399ce4b0d5e89e21a70e",
          "date": "201806121008",
          "id": "12842403173",
          "lang": "English",
          "username": null,
          "followerCount": 0
        },
        {
          "title": "The 5 Greatest BlackBerry Movement Cases And Covers You Can Discover",
          "summary": "... an analogous worth to the iPhone. Presents a report on Brazil... decide assigned your case. With iPhone having gone from boring to...",
          "sourceName": "SocialGist",
          "url": "http://ellington28tuttle.blog.fc2.com/blog-entry-1.html",
          "date": "201806121008",
          "id": "13610660982",
          "lang": "English",
          "username": null,
          "followerCount": 0
        },
        {
          "title": "#GrandSale: Multi-Purpose Power Bank Diary with 16 GB Pen Drive at the Lowest Price!!",
          "summary": "PAN India Delivery | Super Sale | Grab Now | Stock Limited ‌    IPhone and Android Charging Everywhere    You Go!    Note Your Important Tasks And Carry    Your Data Everywhere In 16 GB Pen Drive!                  Unsubscribe from further emails ",
          "sourceName": "SocialGist",
          "url": "http://su2008.blogspot.com/2018/06/grandsale-multi-purpose-power-bank_12.html",
          "date": "201806121006",
          "id": "13391419360",
          "lang": "English",
          "username": null,
          "followerCount": 0
        },
        {
          "title": "MARVELL MINIPOINT DRIVERS FOR MAC",
          "summary": "... the original first-generation Apple iPhone. By using this site, you...",
          "sourceName": "SocialGist",
          "url": "http://gracechurchblog.com/marvell-minipoint-22/",
          "date": "201806121004",
          "id": "13159247849",
          "lang": "English",
          "username": null,
          "followerCount": 0
        },
        {
          "title": "Apple to officially bless USB-C with 2019 iPhone",
          "summary": "... bless USB-C with 2019 iPhone",
          "sourceName": "SocialGist",
          "url": "https://mspoweruser.com/apple-to-officially-bless-usb-c-with-2019-iphone/",
          "date": "201806121000",
          "id": "13610695286",
          "lang": "English",
          "username": null,
          "followerCount": 0
        },
        {
          "title": "ListVR iPhone app offers a new way to create 360-degree tours",
          "summary": "ListVR is an iPhone app that connects to 360-capable cameras, notably the industry-popular Ricoh Theta, to help listing agents rapidly prepare and share panoramic property tours. ",
          "sourceName": "SocialGist",
          "url": "https://www.inman.com/2018/06/12/listvr-iphone-app-offers-a-new-way-to-create-360-degree-tours/",
          "date": "201806121000",
          "id": "14395504944",
          "lang": "English",
          "username": null,
          "followerCount": 0
        },
        {
          "title": "ListVR iPhone app offers a new way to create 360-degree tours",
          "summary": "ListVR is an iPhone app that connects to 360-capable cameras, notably the industry-popular Ricoh Theta, to help listing agents rapidly prepare and share panoramic property tours.",
          "sourceName": "SocialGist",
          "url": "http://helenatalbot.com/real-estate-news/listvr-iphone-app-offers-a-new-way-to-create-360-degree-tours/",
          "date": "201806121000",
          "id": "12619064452",
          "lang": "English",
          "username": null,
          "followerCount": 0
        },
        {
          "title": "My tweets",
          "summary": "... that the tunes on my iPhone go back five decades...train...",
          "sourceName": "SocialGist",
          "url": "https://semi-retired.livejournal.com/273159.html",
          "date": "201806121000",
          "id": "14172002854",
          "lang": "English",
          "username": null,
          "followerCount": 0
        },
        {
          "title": "7 Retail Marketing Predictions to Watch for in 2018",
          "summary": "... into Apple products, including the iPhone. This should encourage retailers to... their home. By using their iPhone to scan the floor of...",
          "sourceName": "SocialGist",
          "url": "https://www.shutterstock.com/blog/retail-marketing-predictions-2018",
          "date": "201806121000",
          "id": "13498756944",
          "lang": "English",
          "username": null,
          "followerCount": 0
        }
      ],
      "providerName": "Blogs",
      "next": "10",
      "success": true,
      "message": "",
      "warnings": [

      ],
      "elapsed": 1470
    }, {
      "totalHits": 256648,
      "results": [{
          "title": "Re: Interesting Find",
          "summary": "I’m just glad you lost Interest in that civic! \n\n\nSent from my iPhone using Tapatalk",
          "sourceName": "SocialGist",
          "url": "http://www.silveradosierra.com/viewtopic.php?t=698984",
          "date": "201806121007",
          "id": "64274658187",
          "lang": "English",
          "username": null,
          "followerCount": 0
        },
        {
          "title": "RE: June OG Thread",
          "summary": "... help! [emoji6]   \nBabbled from my iPhone using Tapatalk",
          "sourceName": "SocialGist",
          "url": "http://www.myproana.com/index.php?showtopic=3437490",
          "date": "201806121007",
          "id": "54643172018",
          "lang": "English",
          "username": null,
          "followerCount": 0
        },
        {
          "title": "RE: I've sold a few seiko's and bought a Tudor.",
          "summary": "[QUOTE=tritto;2623213]Very nice, Paul. \nAlways good to sell a few watches to get something special. \nI've been lucky enough to try on a BB for size, but it wasn't for me. One day I hope to raise funds for a BB58, if it's as good as they say it it. \n\n\nSent from my iPhone using Tapatalk[/QUOTE]\nThanks, the 58 is very nice, go for it.",
          "sourceName": "SocialGist",
          "url": "http://www.thewatchsite.com/showpost.php?p=2623285",
          "date": "201806121006",
          "id": "45444078634",
          "lang": "English",
          "username": null,
          "followerCount": 0
        },
        {
          "title": "Re: The Brotherhood of Submariner Homages  (a/k/a BSHT) (Part 26)",
          "summary": "... reading that. \n\n\nSent from my iPhone using Tapatalk",
          "sourceName": "SocialGist",
          "url": "http://forums.watchuseek.com/showpost.php?p=46266443",
          "date": "201806121006",
          "id": "73149119344",
          "lang": "English",
          "username": null,
          "followerCount": 0
        },
        {
          "title": "RE: Hip X-Rays, what do you think?",
          "summary": "... really worried. \n\n\nSent from my iPhone using Tapatalk",
          "sourceName": "SocialGist",
          "url": "http://www.goldenretrieverforum.com/showpost.php?p=7633612",
          "date": "201806121003",
          "id": "47586878135",
          "lang": "English",
          "username": null,
          "followerCount": 0
        },
        {
          "title": "RE: finally got around to doing a “first wax”",
          "summary": "[quote=kastner03;260386]believe it or not i enjoy doing it when i have the time,  finding the time is the hard part lol\n\n\n Sent from my iPhone using Tapatalk[/quote]\n\n\nMe too.  I find it very \"medicinal\".",
          "sourceName": "SocialGist",
          "url": "http://www.terrainforum.net/showpost.php?p=260450",
          "date": "201806121001",
          "id": "67999278969",
          "lang": "English",
          "username": null,
          "followerCount": 0
        },
        {
          "title": "RE: 突然想买个二手果机.发现这里大部分比二手平台还要贵",
          "summary": "                                      二手全原iphone+V:yuyang2031                ",
          "sourceName": "SocialGist",
          "url": "http://tieba.baidu.com/p/5738028280#post_content_120238939677",
          "date": "201806121000",
          "id": "40498750044",
          "lang": "English",
          "username": null,
          "followerCount": 0
        },
        {
          "title": "RE: Filter Box Cover Question",
          "summary": "[QUOTE=Lt4Mike;2357289]I’m at lunch at the moment so I’ll double check but I’m pretty sure it is a sort of carbon filter. Give me about an hour and I’ll be back. \n\n\nSent from my iPhone using Tapatalk[/QUOTE]\n\nman, that's a long lunch break!  lol",
          "sourceName": "SocialGist",
          "url": "http://www.ctsvowners.com/forum/showpost.php?p=2358281",
          "date": "201806120958",
          "id": "49424983244",
          "lang": "English",
          "username": null,
          "followerCount": 0
        },
        {
          "title": "Re: Plug wire Resistance",
          "summary": "You’re due for a plug wire change anyway. Unless you have a high tension lead tester, you’re not going to get a perfect reading on them. \n\n\nSent from my iPhone using Tapatalk",
          "sourceName": "SocialGist",
          "url": "http://www.silveradosierra.com/viewtopic.php?t=698964",
          "date": "201806120957",
          "id": "64274499979",
          "lang": "English",
          "username": null,
          "followerCount": 0
        },
        {
          "title": "Bond update:",
          "summary": "... of September's new iPhone announcement. Remember, historically this runs...",
          "sourceName": "SocialGist",
          "url": "http://investorshub.advfn.com/boards/read_msg.aspx?message_id=141473816",
          "date": "201806120956",
          "id": "90775052429",
          "lang": "English",
          "username": null,
          "followerCount": 0
        }
      ],
      "providerName": "???",
      "next": "10",
      "success": true,
      "message": "",
      "warnings": [

      ],
      "elapsed": 1470
    }];
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <div ng-repeat="r in response.providerResults">
    <h2>{{r.providerName}} <small>({{r.totalHits}} hits)</small></h2>
    <div>
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th ng-repeat="(key,value) in r.results[0]">{{key}}</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr ng-repeat="item in r.results">
            <td ng-repeat="(key,value) in item">{{value}}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

don't do foreach. When you get the response from the http call just do

```
  $scope.providerResponseResults = response.providerResults;
```

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't resolve it. As per @Lex it needs nested ng-repeat